# Firestore - Create document attributes path dynamically and update value

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update an attribute in a document. The path is dynamic, see picture and code. I get into the then block, but nothing changes in the database. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

```
await updateDoc(updateRef, {
  [`${path[day_[0]].content}`]: workingTime //'F1','N1','S1',
  [`${path[day_[0]].value}`]: workingTime, //'F1','N1','S1'
}).then(() => {
   setOpen(true);
   loadFromFirebase();
});
```